# Accessing WordPress query var from a function hooked to woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to perform a check before adding a product to a WooCommerce cart. The check is based on a value stored in a WordPress query var. The problem is I can not access the $WP_Query from a function fired on the *woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation* hook. 
The basic idea I'm trying to use for that is expressed in the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'the_function_to_go_with', 1, 5);

function the_function_to_go_with($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $WP_Query;
    $product_city = get_query_var('product_city');
    $product_cat = get_query_var('product_cat');

    *// a set of if clauses for the actual check* 
}
```

If printed out to a file, the $WP_Query returns NULL. So, neither the query vars are returned.

An advice of what I am missing here would be much appreciated.